# UITextView not starting from first line in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, textview

I've added a `UITextView` and when it starts editing, it doesn't start at the first line instead from the second line. Anyone have any idea? Thanks!

P.S. This problem continues even I haven't yet implement any code to it.

[image]

Comment: If you are adding `UITextView` in the interface builder (xib file), please, make sure you don't have any empty lines in the text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enter/start text at top of the `UITextView` you need to set `contentInset` such like

```
self.yourTextViewName.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0,1.0,0,0.0); // set value as per your requirement.
```

Generally `contentInset` is use for set the distance of the inset between the content view and the enclosing `UITextView`.

Answer (score 3):

The textView is being pushed down by the extended layout property when you added in the UINavigationController.

Try putting in your ViewDidLoad method

```
  [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
```

Answer (score 3):

in the viewDidLoad method add

object-c:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

swift:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same through binding as well. See the below screen shot:-
[image]

Inside the control ->alignment select first option as above:-

[image]

And then this is the output above:-

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by this way also

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
   UITextView *tv = object;
   //Center vertical alignment
   //CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height * [tv zoomScale])/2.0;
   //topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
   //tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};

   //Bottom vertical alignment
   CGFloat topCorrect = ([tv bounds].size.height - [tv contentSize].height);
    topCorrect = (topCorrect <0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect);
    tv.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
}
```